# Vite Build with Laravel Absolute Path Config

Tags: laravel, vite

I just want to use Vite in production in Laravel and when I run build command, Vite produces css and js files. Therefore, I import them with `@vite()` function in the blade file. But in the production, vite creates the source as the whole URL with domain for the imported css and js files. How can I only give the absolute path like `/build/css/app.74637622352.css`? I don't want to use the domain in the source of my local files.

I tried giving the `base` option in `vite.config.js` but it did not work.